# How to fix escaping of HTML after rails upgrade from Rails 2 to Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping

I have a rails application which uses rails 2.3.8 . I am planning to upgrade it to 3.0.10. For that , I have used the rails_upgrade gem to change the configuration files. However after upgrade to newer version , I could see the entire layout is messed up and the html are getting escaped . For eg, I am seeing &lt instead of < and &gt instead of > . Initially I suspected the older haml gem as the reason of escaping the html . However I changed the Gem file to have the latest haml gem . I am using haml 4.0.5. What I am missing .This is making me mad . Any help is appreciated. Is this because of incompatible gems or some configuration messed up ?
Code for the view is pasted here.

```
%table.grid.full
  %tr
    %td.grid.full_panels
      -table_panel "Project Listing" do
        %table.treetable_trigger
          %thead
            %tr 
              %th Name
              %th priority
              -Project::PLATFORM_OPTIONS.each do |platform_name,platform|
                %th=platform_name
              %th ICs 
          %tbody
            - for project in @projects
              %tr{:class => cycle(:odd, :even), :id => dom_id(project)}
                -if project.prj_disabled? #if project is disabled add color to title and disabled notification
                  %td.nowrap.body_only_tooltip_trigger{:title => project.description+ " <pre><strong>CURRENTLY DISABLED</strong></pre>"}= link_to project.name, project, {:style=>'color:#FF0000;'}
                -else
                  %td.nowrap.body_only_tooltip_trigger{:title => project.description}= link_to project.name, project
                -if project.priority == 28
                  - proj_priority = "Low"
                -elsif project.priority == 4
                  - proj_priority = "Medium"
                -else
                  - proj_priority = "High"    
                %td= proj_priority
                -for platform in Project::PLATFORMS
                  %td= project.send(platform) ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'
                %td= pluralize project.exclusions_count, "Exclusion"

=javascript_include_tag 'pages/project_index.min.js'
```

The html is getting escaped while creating a grid panel .

Comment: Can you post the `view code` where the `HTML` is being escaped?

Comment: @Pavan Pasted my view code. You have any clue on this

Answer (score 1):

You are embedding HTML tags (pre and strong) in this line.

```
%td.nowrap.body_only_tooltip_trigger{:title => project.description+ " <pre><strong>CURRENTLY DISABLED</strong></pre>"}= link_to project.name, project, {:style=>'color:#FF0000;'}
```

Just add `.html_safe` to the string fragment that has the HTML.

```
%td.nowrap.body_only_tooltip_trigger{:title => project.description+ " <pre><strong>CURRENTLY DISABLED</strong></pre>".html_safe}= link_to project.name, project, {:style=>'color:#FF0000;'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to break this down . I don't know why html_safe was not working , I replace the concat in helpers with safe_concat . Rails 3 should not be used with concat .
It will cause escaping of the javascript .